# each page in the back-office required re-login and bottom dev panel is not shown

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, php-7.1

I have prestashop installed locally on my mac pro and macbook pro without any problems.

I wanted to go on production, I created a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform, and installed prestashop from git (branch `stable` version 1.7.2.4) on php 7.1.13 with mariadb 10.3.4 as the database and apache 2.4.10 for the web server.

I have two problems.

1. using the back-office, whenever I try to browse a different page, it asks me to re-login.
2. in the back-office, the bottom dev mode panel is not shown.

I notice that after I login, in google chrome developer console i see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'advices_to_display' of null
    at Object.success (gamification_bt.js:24)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

I don't know if that's related to my issues.

I also checked the cookies and saw that i have a cookie called `PHPSESSID`
and it's value doesn't get changed when I try to re-login so it's new as if it created a new session.

my `phpinfo()` output is at https://pste.eu/p/q75K.html

I tried without apache modules `mod_security2` and `mod_evasive` but the problem persists.

I checked the requirements and enabled all the relevant php modules (can see that in the phpinfo output) but it also didn't change anything.

I'm a bit lost so any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

## update

I noticed that when I go to orders page i see these errors in google chrome developer console:

```
index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1012 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'has_errors' of null
    at Object.success (index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1012)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
success @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1012
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
b @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ VM2175:1
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
refresh_box_conversion_rate @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1005
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1614
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
refresh_kpis @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1607
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:956
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1052 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'has_errors' of null
    at Object.success (index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1052)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
success @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1052
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
b @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ VM2175:1
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
refresh_box_carts @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1045
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1614
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
refresh_kpis @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1607
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:956
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1092 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'has_errors' of null
    at Object.success (index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1092)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
success @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1092
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
b @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ VM2175:1
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
refresh_box_average_order @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1085
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1614
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
refresh_kpis @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1607
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:956
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1132 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'has_errors' of null
    at Object.success (index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1132)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
success @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1132
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
x @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
b @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ VM2175:1
send @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
refresh_box_net_profit_visit @ index.php?controller=AdminOrders&token=89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922:1125
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1614
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
each @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
refresh_kpis @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:1607
(anonymous) @ admin.js?v=1.7.2.0:956
j @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
K @ jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
util.js:248 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
TC.j @ util.js:248
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:147
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:62
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:60
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:62
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:125
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:60
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:125
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:60
(anonymous) @ js?v=3.exp:125
ae @ js?v=3.exp:62
$d.na @ js?v=3.exp:125
(anonymous) @ util.js:1
js?v=3.exp:38 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
_.Pb @ js?v=3.exp:38
(anonymous) @ common.js:54
(anonymous) @ common.js:199
c @ common.js:48
(anonymous) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.xn----3hckih2ap0e.co.il%2Fadmin-dev%2Findex.php%3Fcontroller%3DAdminOrders%26token%3D89ba607af3ec7e91bba30f2f9358a922&callback=_xdc_._vg6xgl&token=72227:1
```

again don't know if it's even related.. just trying to provide as much information as I can.

the problem is also not related to some kind of timeout, cause even after a second that I try to load a different page, it asks me to re-login.

Comment: Have you debug the cookie validity? Or could be an ip related issue. Try going to Administration -> Preferences and disabled the check cookie's ip address check. Also there you can set the cookie lifetime.

Comment: @sadlyblue - welp.. disabling the ip check fixed the problem. thank you :) any ideas why my bottom prestashop debug panel is not visible ? I thought that the problems relate, but they aren't. anyhow, post it as an answer and i'll accept it. this may deserve a different stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If back office is requiring to login can be because of two things:

1. Your ip changed and Prestashop is set to check the Employee ip;
2. Cookie expired or not being received by the server;

To check if it's the first scenario, go to Administration -> Preferences and disable the check cookie's ip address.
Since you have a kubernetes cluster, your ip changing could be a result of the way the cluster is setup/work.

If it's a cookie related issue, can be debugged by checking the cookie set, and if it's received by the server.

As for the debug toolbar is only shown when the debug mode is on, and in pages using symfony. For example in products page and modules. To enable the debug mode, you either edit the file `config/defines.inc.php` and set `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` or in Advanced Parameters -> Performance and set Debug Mode to yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following method:

Login to the admin panel (or Back Office)

CONFIGURE -> Administration -> Advanced Parameters -> GENERAL

[image: Helper Image]

Disable `Check the cookie's IP address` setting and Save the settings by clicking on the 'Save' button.